# Есть ли официальные рекомендации о том, какой максимальный размер JavaScript допустим на сайте?

Tags: javascript, webpack, frontend, производительность

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли какие нибудь общие официальные рекомендации, о том, сколько максимально килобит JavaScript может быть на странице, что бы страницу можно было бы считать быстрой и удобной для пользователя, с точки зрения отрисовки и быстродействия?**

Я понимаю, что чем меньше JavaScript приходит на страницу, тем лучше, с точки зрения скорости полной отрисовки и т.д. Я так же понимаю, что страницы бывают разные по кол-ву функционала и JS на них нужен в разном кол-ве. Но мне просто хочется узнать общий ориентир, цифру, которую в общем и целом превышать не желательно.

Comment: Грамотность кода важнее, чем его количество. Страница может зависнуть и от 100 строчек неграмотного JS. Видел игру, в которой 400.000+ строк JS запускалось в браузере...

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME - это само собою. Качество кода конечно же важно в первую очередь. Но вопрос не совсем об этом. А скорее о том, какое значение размера js взять за ориентир, начиная с которого начинать переживать за удобство пользователя, и начинать пытаться оптимизировать?

Comment: Не с того конца заходите - количество кода практически не влияет. Посмотрите, с каких устройств чаще всего заходят, найдите самое слабое, проверьте на нем. Если не тормозит - не парьтесь)

Answer (score 1):

Нет общей рекомендации, сколько должна весить страница. Но если хотите узнать рекомендации, которые помогут улучшить быстродействие вашей страницы, воспользуйтесь инструментом **Google Lighthouse** – он доступен прямо в инспекторе кода Chrome.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]